# Using RegEx to parse a concatenated string back into individual fields

Tags: regex

I think I'm really close on this RegEx but I was hoping I could get a second set of eyes to help me finish it off. I have a sales history .csv export for a company, and the `item` column in the export is a concatenation of some different fields that I'd like to break down into individual columns again using capture groups. If it has all of the information for an item filled in, the column looks like this:

`Vendor:Item Number (Item Description)`

But sometimes the old system doesn't have vendor, or doesn't have description, so it simply omits those and does not insert a : separator or empty parenthesis. I have lines in the export that look like this:

`Item Number`

`Vendor:Item Number`

`Item Number (Description)`

And, unfortunately,

`Item Number (Description (extra nested parenthesis))`

I'm having trouble with lines that have no descriptions at all, and lines that have nested parenthesis in the description part. This is what I've come up with so far. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

https://regex101.com/r/JEzBAJ/3

Comment: Is it always a whole single line and you only want to parse it or are there also garbage lines that shouldn't match at all? Which language/tool do you want to use?

Comment: For the purposes of this, it can be assumed that each line should at least have something in the Item Number capture group. No garbage lines. @SebastianProske

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can use `:` and `(` as separators here and match everything before an eventual `:` as vendor and everything after an eventual `(` as description.

```
^(?:([^:\n]+):)?([^(\n]+)(.+)?
```

Can thus be used here, note that you have to use Multiline mode, so `^` matches at each start of line, not only at the start of the string.

- `(?:([^:\n]+):)?` - optionally match every non-`:` from the start of the string and the following `:`
- `([^(\n]+)` - matches every non-`(` (if there is none, it will match the reminder of the line)
- `(.+)?` - matches the reminder of the line, if there is any (Thus a `(`) was present.

There is a potential mistake with `Hello (World:Meow)` where `Hello (World` would be matched as vendor - depending if that is a valid case and should be matched as number and description, you might want to adjust the pattern to `^(?:([^(:\n]+):)?([^(\n]+)(.+)?`.

Here are demos for the [first](https://regex101.com/r/EVRb2J/1) and [second](https://regex101.com/r/6iIijL/1) pattern.

Comment: Beautiful. The second pattern is exactly what I was trying to work out. Thank you very much.